# UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification triggers if the app is in background state

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I'm using the following code to get device orientation change notifications.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note{
    UIDevice *device = note.object;
    
    if (device.orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
       // some code here
    }
    
}
```

When the app goes from background to foreground an orientation change notification gets triggered resulting in calling our code which only needs to be called when there's an actual change in orientation.

Are there any other alternative solutions to check orientation changes besides `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` also we cannot use `viewWillTransitionToSize` because our class is not a view.

Comment: Can you store the last orientation and then check against it. If you receive the same orientation and there is nothing to do, then simply ignore it?

Comment: I second that. Plus, it's still possible receive multiple notifications in a row without ever going to background and back. The notification listener should not assume that it will only receive notifications when the orientation actually changes from portrait to landscape and back.

Comment: @RobZombie I'm using the same approach in my code but I'm open to other suggestions.